# symfony2 csrf token invalid on ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, forms, angularjs, symfony

Hi im developing an app with symfony2 and AngularJS. I have a form that i send with $http service over post. Example the login form and the registration form.

The error i get its the classic CSRF token invalid, and that occur when resubmit the form.

The first time the form submit the process go well, the user login or register; but if i logout and try to resubmit the form with the same data to login again i get the error of invalid csrf token.

The in try to regenerate the token if the form its submited with:

*$this->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate');*

and replace it on the view to the next time the form will have a new token to send, but i get the same error.

what im doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to re-render the form for each request?

Comment: no, the idea its that the form its always there or showed or hided in the login wrapped div of the user menu, it will hide or show depending on the logged status of the user

Comment: Did you check that the CSRF token really changes between the requests?

Comment: yes i check that a new token was send after the successful request and changed on _token field on form, but for some reason when i send the form again symfony expect another token different from the first used time and the new one generated in the request

Answer (score 0):

I know that you asked this question a long time ago but today I faced the same issue which solution was quite simple. If you render your form with another nodes, make sure that form_start is in the same node as form_end. 
In my case it looked like this:

```
<div>
{{form_start(form)}}
... some form inputs
</div>
{{form_end(form)}}
```

As you probably know that the form_end renders the token (in latest Symfony) and as a result, the token was outside the form.

As it happens when you try to rerender the form I guess it is because you have other template for rerendered form (ex. with errors) so make sure that your HTML hierarchy is valid.

Hope it will help someone in the future. Cheers!